# Java, a method declaration inside another method?

Tags: java, function, methods

I'm studyin' some Java code written by my ex-colleague, and I've found something I cannot understand properly.
Here we have a method, getGeneAvailableTaxonomies(), that seems to contain a method call with its own declaration, accept().
Is it true? Is it possibile?

Here's the code part: I cannot understand the meaning of the program from FilenameFilter() to the end.

```
public List<Integer> getGeneAvailableTaxonomies() {
    List<Integer> availableTaxon = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    File dataDirectory = new File(_currentApplicationPath, String.format("Data"));
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("gene_") && name.endsWith("_info.info"); //get all info files...
        }
    };
    String[] children = dataDirectory.list(filter);

    for(String child:children) {
        availableTaxon.add(Integer.parseInt(child.substring(child.indexOf("_")+1, child.lastIndexOf("_"))));
    }

    return availableTaxon;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The part of the code where you see the `accept()` method being defined is what's called an anonymous class.

> ```
> FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
>     public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
>         return name.startsWith("gene_") && name.endsWith("_info.info"); //get all info files...
>     }
> };
> ```

What's going on here is the creation of a new Class that is-a FilenameFilter.  They're implementing/overriding the accept method.  Think of it like this, but in one statement:

```
class MyFilenameFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith("gene_") && name.endsWith("_info.info"); 
    }
}

FilenameFilter filter = new MyFilenameFilter()
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. So, this second part you wrote has the same meanin' of my code, is it right?

Comment: it would accomplish the same thing, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This is anonymous inner class, i.e. class that does not have its own name and is defined ad-hock together with its instance.

Actually the name of this class is as name of your outer class followed by $ and number (1, 2, 3 etc.) according to the sequential number of your inner class.

Answer (score 1):

The 'inner' method is a filter for the 'outer' method that decides if a file inside `dataDirectory` will be included or not in the String array.

To get this functionality, he implemented the `accept` method of the `FilenameFilter` interface. Since only that one method was needed, it was more convenient to implement it directly in the code (as an anonymous class) than to create a separate class that implemented the 'whole' FilenameFilter interface.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I have no university. But I learned from the Internet.

You can do that, it's not "method inside a method". It is implementing an interface.

[FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

You can do [extending an abstract class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) or implementing an interface then apply it directly to a field/ variable. And since variables/ fields can be used inside a method, so that is possible.

**Edited**

You can notice the semicolon after the last curly bracket of `new FilenameFilter() {...`. The whole block is an expression, so it can be applied to fields/ variables...

Answer (score 0):

Those are called anonymous classes. They're described in the JLS, but you might want to read about them in "Java in a Nutshell" or some other tutorials out there to get a better handle on it.

Answer (score 0):

[FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) is an interface. The syntax `new FilenameFilter(){...}` here creates and instantiates an anonymous class which implements `FilenameFilter` with implementation inside.
See [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to check what `dataDirectory.list()` does. "It returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter."

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening.  The syntax is called an *anonymous inner class*.  The `new` gives you a hint that you are creating a new class that inherits from `FilenameFilter` -- which is why it can be assigned to a reference of type `FilenameFilter` -- but that class implements a method named accept that overloads the `FilenameFilter` `accept` method.  That class doesn't have a name visible to the rest of the program (although some compilers at least will create a classfile in the target directory) but its sole instance exists as long as `filter` remains in scope.

This is sort of an almost-lambda that showed up in Java about Java 1.2 (I think.)